# using time intervals between sound failing flash as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

hi need to have a timer class that actually has very descent timming:

```
    var playTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000);
    playTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,playhead);
    playTimer.start();

    function playhead(e:TimerEvent):void
    {

    for ( i = 0; i<myArray.length; i++)
    {
        soundArray[0].play();
                    break;
    }
    }
```

The above works but sadly the sound is not accurate, the sound playing is a clap like noise, theory i would presume it would clap on an even interval but it doesnt. any help would be apreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you are trying to do by  playing a sound multiple times, based on the length of myArray, and then breaking.

But anyways, the the `play()` method of a `Sound` does accept parameters, and one of them is how many times you'd like to loop.

try this alone, without all that timer code etc :

```
sound.play(0,5);
```

The 0 cues it at the beginning of the sound, which is the default.
the 5 specifies to loop 5 times.

Comment: that wont work for what im doing the reason why the sound is set on a timer as this timer will change dynamically think of a music sequencer, so i need to use a timer.and the break is there as it will be eventually playing 8 sounds at once

Comment: You should then modify your question with a bit more detail, to make it easier for someone to help you. I don't see the logic of having a loop iterating through myArray, but yet playing a sound in soundArray.   If you are not clear and concise with your questions, people might not choose to answer.

Comment: i thought my question was clarified plenty with a timer triggering the  function, anyways when i come up with a solution i will post it here..Im thinking on making a timer class

Comment: Just mentioning what you are trying to do in the question - making a music sequencer - is a pretty helpful piece of information that people will only learn if they hit these comments. Also, from your loops in that handler, it left me scratching my head as to what your logic was. Why did you choose to iterate through myArray and play the first sound in soundArray and then break unconditionally. I can't say that I find that plenty clear.

Comment: After much research my logic is good but flash cant keep a very good timer, C# this works fine, suppose more resources.

Comment: My comment on your logic was in regards to -- 'Why did you choose to iterate through myArray and play the first sound in soundArray and then break unconditionally.' -- That is not logical, as only the one sound would EVER be played with that code. Why would you even need a loop if that was your logically desired outcome ?

Comment: In terms of a sequencer, you could have checked out something like this - http://labs.byhook.com/2009/12/04/flash-10-audio-sequencer/ I believe your issue was mostly that you were approaching it from the wrong direction.